# How do I migrate my Zune player (HD) content to a new machine?

Tags: migration, zune, zune-software, zune-hd

I've got a Zune HD loaded with my music from CD.  Unfortunately, the machine it's synched to is running Windows XP.  I dragged a Vista machine out of storage to use to replace my XP box since XP is EOL in a week or 2.  Is there a seamless way to migrate all my stuff either from the Zune HD back onto the new box, or can I migrate the files directly from the Windows XP box over to the Windows Vista box (or, am I out of luck and need to keep this XP box kicking around just to support my music library)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked around for awhile and found a directory on my XP machine called "ZuneMusic" with all the MP3s in it.  I copied that to the Music Documents directory on the Vista machine.  Upon installing and starting up the Zune software, it automatically found all the files there and added them to the catalog.